Find the solution of the eighth-degree polynomial equation with symmetrical structures
To solve the given equation:
$$P_1 + P_3 + P_4 + P_5 = P_2$$
where
\begin{align}
P_1 & = \prod_{i=1,2,3,4;j=1,2}(s-s_{ij}), \\
P_2 & = a\cdot \prod_{i=1,2;j=1,2}(s-s_{ij}), \\
P_3 & = b \cdot \prod_{i=1,3;j=1,2}(s-s_{ij}) \cdot \prod_{i=5,6;j=2} (s-s_{ij}), \\
P_4 & = c \cdot \prod_{i=5,6;j=1,2}(s-s_{ij}), \\
P_5 & = d \cdot \prod_{i=2,4;j=1,2}(s-s_{ij}) \cdot \prod_{i=5,6;j=1}(s-s_{ij})
\end{align}
$s_{11},s_{12},s_{21},s_{22},s_{31},s_{32},s_{41},s_{42},s_{51},s_{52},s_{61},s_{62},a,b,c,d$ are known complex numbers.
I think Galois theory might be helpful. Any help would be very grateful, thank you!
